# how to trigger click on corresponding index

Tags: jquery, indexing

Ok,

I have a `div` of anchors:

```
<div class="allTabs">
<a href="#">link 1a</a>
<a href="#">link 1b</a>
<a href="#">link 1c</a>
<a href="#">link 1d</a>
<a href="#">link 1e</a>
<a href="#">link 1f</a>
<a href="#">link 1g</a>
<a href="#">link 1h</a>
</div>
```

and then a ul:

```
<ul class="ppItemTabs">
<li>
<a href="#">link 2a</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">link 2b</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">link 2c</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">link 2d</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">link 2e</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">link 2f</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">link 2g</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do, is a click function on the `allTabs a` that will grab the index of that a, and then `trigger("click")` on the corresponding index in `.ppItemTabs` (the a).

I've been having issues getting this to work (in other words, everything I've tried has not worked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.allTabs').on('click', 'a', function()
{
    $('.ppItemTabs').find('a:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').trigger('click');
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/6mqBt/](http://jsfiddle.net/6mqBt/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

```
$('.allTabs a').click(function(){
  $('.ppItemTabs li:eq('+$(this).index()+' a').click();
});
```